# Java RMI asynchronous callback OR other solution

Tags: java, rmi

Having a problem with Java RMI.
Is it possible to start an asynchronous callback? So the server doens't need to wait for the methode. The problem is if the server invokes a methode of the client it can happen that the client "blocks" or something else so the server would block too.
Somebody know a good solution for this?
I know about "sun.rmi.transport.tcp.responseTimeout" but i don't like it.
I readed about "client polling" but is this the right way?

//EDIT
another problem is interrupting this callbacks(if they take to long or something else)

sry for bad english ;)
thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

Just start the callback in a separate server thread. But callbacks in RMI are problematic anyway unless you can guarantee there will never be a firewall between client and server.

Comment: well ok starting it in a sseparate thread will follow more problems.    Like how to interrupt it if the server shutdown... i heard about interruptableRMI but i never tried it.

Comment: I never heard about interruptible RMI, and I wrote a book about RMI. If there is more to your question than you've stated you should edit your question.

Comment: Well i found this project on java.net: https://java.net/projects/interruptiblermi                              but with a polling client i can go arround all this problems or?      i edit my starting question new

Comment: I strongly suggest you use client polling, or try to get rid of the two-way communication altogether.